# Receiving error: Class Action is missing in schema: actions.actions

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to broadcast transaction having following actions:

```
actions: [
    transactions.createAccount(),
    transactions.transfer(new BN(swapParams.value.toFixed())),
    transactions.deployContract(new Uint8Array(bytecode)),
    transactions.functionCall(
      ABI.init.method,
      {
        secretHash: Buffer.from(swapParams.secretHash, 'hex').toString('base64'),
        expiration: `${toNearTimestampFormat(swapParams.expiration)}`,
        buyer: swapParams.recipientAddress
      },
      new BN(ABI.init.gas),
      new BN(0)
    )
  ]
```

But when I invoke

```
const tx = await from.signAndSendTransaction(addressToString(options.to), options.actions)
```

I receive following callstack:
[image: Error]

Any idea what might be the reason?

I'm using:

`near-js-api: 0.39.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-cookbook#batch-transactions), [source code, and defined types](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/26b3dd2f55ef97107c429fdfa704de566617c9b3/src/account.ts#L189-L193) `signAndSendTransaction` should take a single argument (an object with `receiverId` and `actions` fields):

```
const tx = await from.signAndSendTransaction({
  receiverId: addressToString(options.to),
  actions: options.actions
})
```

Was there an example/doc that mislead you, so you arrived with this function call interface? We should fix that.